# Optional essays

Tags: graduate-school, graduate-admissions, application, united-states, statement-of-purpose

If  you can upload a writing sample or a second statement of purpose in a  university online application, and the department I am applying for doesn't require these two essays, would I get extra credit (higher chances of getting accepted) if I do upload answers to these questions, or they will not even look at them?

Comment: You're not going to strengthen your application just by uploading something; "bytes of application data" is not part of the application scoring.  There's no way to know whether they will read it or not; some committees might and some might not.  If you want to know about a specific department, you'll have to ask them.  Even if they do read it, then whether it helps you depends on what you actually wrote!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Less is more.  The goal of your application is to present *tangible evidence* that you have the potential to succeed as a researcher (completed papers, projects, and to some degree coursework), and do so as quickly and concisely as possible.  Adding more text simply distracts readers from the "important stuff," which they probably care about less than your letters anyway.  In that vein, I'll stop here.

Comment: What you are saying is logically true, however the bad news is I don't have a published paper yet, or even a related to my proposed field writing sample! so maybe this is a game changer!

Comment: Certainly you have *something* that demonstrates your creative potential.  Class project?  Project you did on your own just for fun?  ...Even if you don't, simply adding more text to your application is not going to help your case!